# Sending char arry via nRF24L01

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to send a char array using Arduino Uno board and nRF24L01 modules

Here is the code for both transmitter and receiver:

```
 #include <SPI.h> //~ #include <TMRh20nRF24L01.h> //~ #include <TMRh20RF24.h>
 #include <nRF24L01.h>
 #include <RF24.h>
 
 
 #define CE_PIN   9
 #define CSN_PIN 10
 
 // NOTE: the "LL" at the end of the constant is "LongLong" type //
 These are the IDs of each of the slaves const uint64_t slaveID[2] =
 {0xE8E8F0F0E1LL, 0xE8E8F0F0E2LL} ;
 
 RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio
 
 char 
> dataToSend[64]="e7665072be018b6b58ea9e40cf38553d6dc293cda4c9d94cda6e91ca61b3a073";
 
 unsigned long currentMillis; unsigned long prevMillis; unsigned long
> txIntervalMillis = 1000; int txVal = 0; float ackMessg[2]={1,2}; byte
 ackMessgLen = 4; // NB this 4 is the number of bytes in the 2 ints
 that will be recieved
 
 
 void setup() {
 
    Serial.begin(9600);
     Serial.println("Track Control Starting");
     radio.begin();
     radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
     radio.enableAckPayload();
     radio.setRetries(3,5); // delay, count }
 
 //====================
 
 void loop() {
 
     currentMillis = millis();
     if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {
 
     radio.openWritingPipe(slaveID[0]); // calls the first slave
                                         // there could be a FOR loop to call several slaves in turn
    
     bool rslt;
     rslt = radio.write( dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) );
     Serial.print("\nRSLT (1 = success) ");
     Serial.println(rslt);
     Serial.print("Data Sent ");
     Serial.print(dataToSend[0]);
     Serial.print("  ");
     Serial.println(dataToSend[1]);
     if ( radio.isAckPayloadAvailable() ) {
         radio.read(ackMessg,ackMessgLen);
        Serial.print("Acknowledge received: ");
        Serial.print(ackMessg[0]);
```

> ```
>  #include <SPI.h>
>  #include <nRF24L01.h>
>  #include <RF24.h>
>  
>  
>  #define CE_PIN   9
>  #define CSN_PIN 10
>  
>  // NOTE: the "LL" at the end of the constant is "LongLong" type
>
>  const uint64_t   deviceID = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL; // Define the ID for this slave
>
> int valChange = 1;
>  
>  RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);
>  
>  char  dataReceived[64];
>  int ackData[2] = {12,23};
>  
>  void setup() {
>  
>      Serial.begin(9600);
>      delay(1000);
>      Serial.println("Hand Controller Starting");
>      radio.begin();
>      radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
>      radio.openReadingPipe(1,deviceID);
>      radio.enableAckPayload();
>      radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackData, sizeof(ackData));
>      radio.startListening();
>  }
>  
>  void loop() {
>  
>      if ( radio.available() ) {
>          radio.read( dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
>           for (int x = 0; x <64; x++) {
>        //if (dataReceived[x] < 16) {
>        //  Serial.write('0');
>      // }
>        Serial.print(dataReceived[x]);}
>        Serial.println();
>          radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackData, sizeof(ackData));
>         
>          ackData[0] += valChange; // this just increments so you can see that new data is being sent
>      }
> }
> ```

And here is the output that I get

> Hand Controller Starting
>
> e7665072be018b6b58ea9e40cf38553d

Comment: you get what you send. continue reading

Comment: yes i know that i got what i sent,my question was how to get the full char array as its size is more than payload size

Comment: To send a larger package you will need to split the data into a sequence of packages of PAYLOAD_MAX(32) size at the sender. And then reassemble the data at the receiver.

Comment: I would expect that the library sends the input in parts even if send in one function call. But I don't know this library. But the receiving must be coded expecting chunks of data.

Comment: yes i am trying to find a way to split big payload into chunks

Comment: Why send 64 characters in hex decimal notation when you can send 32 bytes with the same data?

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: `byte dataToSend[32] = { 0xe7, 0x66, 0x50, 0x72, ..., 0x61, 0xb3, 0xa0, 0x73};` or write a function that translates from character string to byte vector as above.

Comment: thank u very much,but the array is generated from a hash function in sha256 library,i just simplified the code here to discuss the concept

Comment: Yes, the SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE is 32 which happens to be the RF24_PAYLOAD_MAX. The vector size (64) is your example is the textual (ASCII character) hex decimal representation of the block. Double the size as a byte (8-bits) is represented as two ASCII characters (0..15 mapped to '0'..'9', 'A'..'F').

Comment: so can i send the unencoded output from the hash function then map it at the receiver side?

Answer (score 1):

TX code

```
#include "sha256.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "./printf.h"

#include <SPI.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20nRF24L01.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

// NOTE: the "LL" at the end of the constant is "LongLong" type
// These are the IDs of each of the slaves
const uint64_t slaveID = 0xE8E8F0F0E1L  ;

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio

unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 1000;
int txVal = 0;
int ackMessg[6];
byte ackMessgLen = 4; 

uint8_t* hash;
uint8_t copy[32];
void printHash(uint8_t* hash) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]>>4]);
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]&0xf]);
      copy[i]=hash[i];
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  printf_begin();

  uint32_t a;
  unsigned long ms;

  Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_2MBPS );
    radio.enableAckPayload();
    radio.setRetries(3,5); // delay, count

  // SHA tests
  Serial.println("Test: FIPS 180-2 B.1");
  Serial.println("Expect:ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad");
  Serial.print("Result:");
  ms = micros();
  Sha256.init();
  Sha256.print("abc");
  printHash(Sha256.result());
  Serial.println();
  for(int x=0;x<32;x++)
        {   Serial.print(copy[x]);
            Serial.print(" ");  
                                  }
            Serial.println();

  Serial.print(" Hash took : ");
  Serial.print((micros() - ms));
  Serial.println(" micros");
  Serial.println();

  }


void loop() {

  currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {

    radio.openWritingPipe(slaveID); 
    bool rslt,rsltt;
    rslt = radio.write( copy, 32 );

    if ( radio.isAckPayloadAvailable() ) {
        radio.read(ackMessg,ackMessgLen);
        Serial.print("Acknowledge received: ");
        Serial.print(ackMessg[0]);
        Serial.print("  ");
        Serial.println(ackMessg[1]);
    }
    prevMillis = millis();
 }

}
```

Rx code

```
// HandController - the slave or the receiver

    // http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/

    //~ - CONNECTIONS: nRF24L01 Modules See:
    //~ http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo
    //~ 1 - GND
    //~ 2 - VCC 3.3V !!! NOT 5V
    //~ 3 - CE to Arduino pin 9
    //~ 4 - CSN to Arduino pin 10
    //~ 5 - SCK to Arduino pin 13
    //~ 6 - MOSI to Arduino pin 11
    //~ 7 - MISO to Arduino pin 12
    //~ 8 - UNUSED

#include <SPI.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20nRF24L01.h>
//~ #include <TMRh20RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

// NOTE: the "LL" at the end of the constant is "LongLong" type

const uint64_t   deviceID[2] ={ 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL,0xE8E8F0F0E1LL}; // Define the ID for slaves

int valChange = 1;

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);
RF24 radioo(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);
uint8_t  dataReceived[32];

int ackData[2] = {12,23};

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Hand Controller Starting");
    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_2MBPS );
    radio.openReadingPipe(1,deviceID[1]);
    radio.enableAckPayload();
    radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackData, sizeof(ackData));
    radio.startListening();

}

void loop() {

 unsigned long startTimer = millis();

    if ( radio.available() ) {
        radio.read( dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
        radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackData, sizeof(ackData));
        Serial.println();
        //Serial.println(startTimer);
        Serial.println();
        for(int x=0;x<32;x++)
        {Serial.print(dataReceived[x]);
        Serial.print(" ");}}
        ackData[0] += valChange; // this just increments so you can see that new data is being sent

    }
```

it is fully working now with both outputs on the same size